# Leaking gas tank

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

Say we have a rigid tank of nitrogen gas ($N_0$ molecules) at temperature $T$. The tank is in vacuum. If we now punch a small hole on the tank, the gas will leak. Assume the hole is small enough so the gas inside is remains ideal. The tank is not fixed so it is accelerated by the leak. What is the average energy of escaping gas particle?

My thought is, initially, gas particle has an average energy $\frac{5}{2}kT$. If we punch a hole, the gas leaks in just one direction so the leaked gas should have an average energy of $\frac{3}{2}kT$ (1 spacial and 2 rotational d.o.f.). Since temperature is a measure of average kinetic energy, does that mean the temperature in the tank actually increases during the leak? This seems very strange to me.

Comment: Concerning your last point about the temperature, it seems unlikely that the escaping gas molecules are in thermal equilibrium, and so it's not meaningful to assign a temperature to them.